# Recover the field from one Drupal page to another

Tags: 6, nodes

What I want to do is recovering the avatar picture the Avatar Selection module generates, and present it elsewhere in my Drupal installation, specifically in pages where it is not appearing.

I have been referred to the `dsm()` function, but not being a programmer, I am utterly lost with this. I haven't got a clue.
I know that I need to know the field's name, where the picture is showing and then I can render it, but while I know all this, I have no clue as how to do it or if this is all I need.

I haven't found (or haven't understood) any `dsm()` tutorials out there.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `dsm()`.   You have to install a devel module.  In you code if you do `dsm($user)` then it would show you a nice user interface of the $user object/array

[image: Drupal user object]

The location to the user picture (or avatar) is in your $user->picture object.  If $user array is not available, then you can do `global $user;`

Comment: Thank you so much, iStryker. And do I paste "dsm($user)", for instance, in the part that resembles the body in an html page?

Comment: To display what is in the image, then yes

Comment: Well, you definitely pointed me in the right direction. I have an output that shows the path of the image, but not the image, so I guess I'll get it eventually. I used "picture", but I'm missing something then.

Comment: $html_picture = theme('image', array('path' => $user->picture, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $title) you'll have to define $title & $alt.

Comment: I see. Being that this is very Drupal-oriented, is there a PHP parallel that I could study or learn to understand how this works from the beginning? Thank you very much, indeed.

Comment: no not really.  Checkout api.drupal.org for all the drupal core functions, and http://drupalcontrib.org/drupal-6-modules for contrib api